# Is strlen() safe from injection?

Tags: php, html, security

Is it safe to run `strlen()` on user input from a HTML form? Or are there ways to break out of the function and inject unwanted code.

Answer (score 2):

yes it's safe. all it does is count how many bytes are in the string. It doesn't eval code or anything.

you should be weary of using `eval()` `system()` or putting the user input in a database query or writing to a file without first validating the info.

Comment: The number of `bytes`, not the number of `characters`.

Comment: @DevlshOne fair enough, fixed

Answer (score 2):

Unless a new bug is found in PHP's codebase for `strlen()` you can count on it being safe to use with user input.